# Passing Data between View Controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to convert an app from Objective-C to Swift but I can't find how to pass data between views using Swift.  My Objective-C code is

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
AnsViewController *ansViewController;
ansViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ansView"];
ansViewController.num = theNum;
[self presentViewController:ansViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What that is doing is it basically takes the variable, theNum, and passes it to the variable, num, on a different view controller.  I know this may be an easy question but I am getting pretty confused with Swift so if someone could explain how they changed it to Swift that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Its exactly the same in Swift, what exactly are you unsure about?

Comment: Just the Swift syntax in general. I know that I wouldn't be able to use the square brackets in Swift but in the eBook, it uses a . or parentheses at certain times and I'm not sure which one to use here

Comment: The dot and parentheses syntaxes are very general programming syntaxes found in almost every language. To be **very** brief, `()` is used to call a function, `.` accesses members/properties/functions of a class/struct/etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have most of it figured out now except for the ansViewController.num = theNum part because it says UIViewController does not have a member named theNum

Comment: [Here is a basic example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31934101/3681880)

Comment: @lagoon Would you mind accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's assumed we stand at the **firstView** go to the **DetailView** and want passing data from firstView to Detailview. To do that with storyboard, at the firstView we will have a method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
      //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
      // segues attached to same view
      var detailVC = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController;
      detailVC.toPass = textField.text
    }
}
```

and then into the class of **DetailView** we declared a variable:

```
var toPass: String!
```

then you can use the variable `toPass` (of course you can change the type of the variable as you want, in this EX I just demo for string type).

Comment: best solution if you need something quick and easy! Thanks

Comment: This looks like what I am needing. I want to pass an array of variables from VC 1 to VC 2. Then, in VC 2, the user will enter information into more fields. That information will be appended to the array. When done, the array is sent to the cloud.

I copied your code into my project and replaced my var names. I am getting an error, 'DispScreenOne does not have a member named 'toPass'.

`{if (segue.identifier == "goToDispenseScreenTwo") {
var DispScreenOne = segue.destinationViewController as! DispenseScreenTwoViewController;
DispScreenOne.toPass = enteredDataArray.text
}`

Comment: @Greg: Please make sure at **DispenseScreenTwoViewController**, you have a variable name **toPass**

Comment: @Lee: I have a global var toPass. When I try to set a value to toPass in any of my view controllers, it recognizes the var.  What am I missing?

Comment: You have a global variable toPass into your project doesn't mean **DispenseScreenTwoViewController** have this variable. So that you will get the error: **'DispScreenOne does not have a member named 'toPass'**.

Comment: **DispScreenOne.toPass** mean that: at **DispenseScreenTwoViewController** you must have a variable name **toPass**

Comment: it is not working unable to get value on second controller which is passed by first contrioller.

Answer (score 19):

```
class AnsViewController: UIViewController {
   var theNum: Int

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(theNum)
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ansView") as AnsViewController
    viewController.num = theNum
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: where to give view controller identifier

Comment: @zainullah In the Storyboard ID.

Answer (score 2):

To pass string or any data from one controller to another in swift.

Follows below steps:

1) Create property in child controller as `var abc:string!`

2) Create object of childcontroller

```
let storyboard:UIStoryboard()
let viewController: childcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("childcontroller") as! childcontroller
viewController.abc = "hello";
self.navigationController.pushviewController(Controller:viewController animated:true CompletionHandler:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using tableview,

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            let ClubProfileView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CBClubProfileViewController") as! CBClubProfileViewController

            let TempCulubDic:NSDictionary =
                ((ClubsListbyDateDic.object(forKey:((ClubsListbyDateDic.allKeys as! [String]).sorted(by: <)as NSArray).object(at: indexPath.section) as! String) as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row))as! NSDictionary

            let ClubId:String=(TempCulubDic.value(forKey: "club_id") as? String)!

            let CheckIndate:String=(TempCulubDic.value(forKey: "chekin_date") as? String)!

            ClubProfileView.ClubID=ClubId

            ClubProfileView.CheckInDate = CheckIndate

            // self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden=true

            ClubProfileView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ClubProfileView, animated: true)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @IBAction func nextbtnpreesd(_ sender: Any) {

            let mystring = "2"
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "MusicVC", sender: mystring)
        }



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        if let destination = segue.destination as? MusicVC{

            if let song = sender as? String{
                destination.strlablevalie = song
            }
        }
    }
```

//in MusicVC create string like:

```
 var strlablevalie:String!
```

Comment: it is not working unable to get value on second controller which is passed by first contrioller. – Chandni 2 mins ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

To pass string or any data from one controller to another in swift.

Follows below steps:

1) Create variable of type which you want like (String,Int)
var test : String!

2) Create object of childcontroller

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Here identifier of your VC") as! (Here Name Of Your Controller)
 vc.test = "Hello" (Or any data which you want to pass)
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

That should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Note: if we are using storyboard

Step 1: Master controller :

```
    // table row which row was selected
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

        nextScreenRow = indexPath.row

        // get to the next screen
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dashboard_static_screen_segue", sender: self)

    }
```

and then;

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if (segue.identifier == "dashboard_static_screen_segue") {
            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as StaticScreens;
            detailController.screenNumber = nextScreenRow
        }

    }// end prepareForSegue
```

step 2: Detail controller (StaticScreen)

```
// set variable into your detail controller

var screenNumber: NSInteger?

println("selected row \(screenNumber!)")
```