# Accessing Variables in other viewcontroller - swift

Tags: swift

I want to access the variable `answerdata` in the second viewcontroller. I am pretty new in swift a I`ve tried a lot of options, but nothing worked.

Code in the first viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class prvnidotaz: UIViewController {

var pickerdata = ["Small","Big","Medium"]


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) ->Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->Int {
        return pickerdata.count
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)->String!{
        return pickerdata [row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      var answerdata = pickerdata [row]
        println(answerdata)
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26374173/1271826. I would generally recommend the `prepareForSegue` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your var answerdata is defined as a local variable.

You can access answerdata from a second controller if you define it as an instance variable, also known as "property".