# How to access variables from one controller to another controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, var

Hi all am developing a app using swift 2.2 i declared a variable in first view controller i want to access that in second view controller.i have searched other stack overflow answers nothing supports me.

In my first view controller:

```
class firstViewController: UIViewController{

var timer:nstimer?
//performed some functions using nstimer
}
```

Now i want to stop the timer and i kept button action in the second view controller so i want to access the variable timer.how to access??

I searched before stack overflow answers that asked to use prepare for segue but am already given some connection and performed segue to other controllers.

Now am looking for the solution to access that variables.can anyone help me out from this problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift

Comment: using storyboard identifier and prepare for segue will cause any problem to the project??

Comment: because am using many view controllers and uses many segues between view controllers

Comment: no! it won't create any problem. and in prepareforsegue you can check identifier name. but keep in mind two identifier name should not be same.

Comment: no need to access timer var from second ctrlr. set a delegate, and the implementation in first ctrlr stop the timer. So from second ctrlr call delegate.stopTimer(). btw better to move Swift 3

Comment: i have almost completed by application thats what i cant able to move to swift3

Comment: @antonyraja check my answer. it won't create any problem.

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials and examples available regarding your issue you can google little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second ViewController shouldn't know anything about the first view controller, if it does then you essentially tie both VC's together.

What you need to do instead is either pass a reference through like @Sahil suggested above (although I would refrain from doing that as the first VC might not expect a change from an external source), or use a delegate pattern.

With a  delegate pattern you give the second VC a weak reference to the first VC and have the first VC conform to a protocol defined by the second VC. The delegate pattern has been explained many times over so I'll just give you a link instead of explaining it again here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

The delegate pattern is the safest option and it allows the first VC to control the timer in an expected way rather than having it modified externally, so I would recommend exploring that option instead of passing a reference to the timer through.

Comment: @antonyraja there is an example in the link that I posted. It explains the delegate concept as a whole so you can understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

In `FirstController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueidentifier" {

     if let destVc = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
      destVc.timer = self.timer
    }
 }
}
```

In `SecondViewController` create a timer property and use it.

```
var timer: NSTimer?
```

and if you are getting problem with connecting. try this

Create segue between FirstViewController and SecondViewController by ctrl + drag and connect to second and give name to segue identifier

[image]

Comment: if segue.identifier == "segueidentifier"

Comment: if segue.identifier == "segueidentifier" .here what identifier i have to give..??

Comment: you need to click on segue and give the identifier name  on right side
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=segue+identifier+swift&espv=2&biw=1229&bih=548&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9xPu7zpvQAhUKPo8KHWrnB2QQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=eKAWRN9Aycd5YM%3A

Comment: there is no option like segue....there is show and custom only....is it possible to use storyboard id??

Comment: check my updated answer. and for more http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/

Comment: it shows me three popup i.e....show custom and push....which should i have to select??

Comment: it depends . if your first controller  embed in navigation controller select push else select present modally. you need to read http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/ carefully.

Comment: variable accessed but if i press the button action...timer.invalidate not working it keeps on calling the function nstimer....but nothing shows error....what to do????

Comment: in my firstvc: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "pushsegue" {
            
            var destVc = segue.destinationViewController as! LeftSideViewController
            destVc.timer = self.timer
        }
in my secondvc:i declared again var timer:nstimer?..like what i declare in firstvc........In button action:timer?.invalidate()

Comment: have you checked ref in secondViewController viewDidLoad? if not please check print(self.timer)

Comment: self.timer =??...what i have to provide?

Comment: sorry. i meant print the timer

Comment: why should i have to print timer...and it is not possible to print

Comment: debug the code and check timer object is not nil. if it is successfully passed data in secondviewcontroller and you called timer?.invalidate(). timer should  be stopped.

Comment: we have to declare var timer:nstimer! in both view controller??or else first vc is enough

Comment: Yes in both view controllers.