# How do I pass JSON data between controller in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, json, swift3, uilabel, xcode8

I have these JSON data:

```
{"login":"ET001","email":"email@try.com"}
```

In Swift 3.0, I created two files which are LoginVC and ViewController.

ViewController can only be accessed after LoginVC verified the credentials. So far I managed to make the login access the ViewController page based on "success" JSON data from database.

But my next goal is to **pass the JSON data "[login]" from LoginVC into ViewController**.

In ViewController, I created **UILabel "loginLbl"** to display the JSON value from LoginVC.

How do update my code?

#### LoginVC.swift

```
import UIKit
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var _login: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var _pass: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UILabel!

    var login: String!
    var pass: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad()}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tocey"{
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            destination.passedData = self.outputLbl.text
            print("Sender value is : \(sender)")
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func loginData(_ sender: Any) {

    login = _login.text
    pass  = _pass.text

    if(login == "" || pass == "") {

        return
    }
    else {
        let url             = URL(string: "http://localhost/login.php")
        let session         = URLSession.shared

        let request         = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod  = "POST"

        let paramToLogin    = "login=\(login!)&pass=\(pass!)"
        request.httpBody    = paramToLogin.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            else {
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String] {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let success  = Int(json["success"]!)
                            let loginvaluefromdb = json["login"]
                            if(success == 1){
                                    self.outputLbl.text = loginvaluefromdb;

                                    let abc = json["login"]
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tocey", sender: abc)
                                    return
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                    }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var loginLbl: UILabel!

    var passedData: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginLbl.text = passedData
    }
}
```

How to pass it into **UILabel loginLbl**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift)

Comment: Yes , i know this question may be duplicate . But i still confuse on how to pass the data . .

Comment: @AlotJai There is no code of navigation in your code.

Comment: you mean that navigation from LoginVC to ViewController ?

Comment: @AlotJai yes i'm taking about that navigation.

Comment: I'll update shortly .

Comment: I already update the question code . can you take a look on it  ? thanks.

Comment: @AlotJai Still there is no call for `perfromSegue`.

Comment: i add it inside loginData action function

Comment: You need to to add `performSegue` on success. And in `prepareForSegue` pass the string to the destination `UIViewController`. You can find plenty of questions regarding the same issue.

Comment: where to add prepareForSegue ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you identify that login data is correct in your response you need to push your viewController in navigation controller and take one dictionary in your viewController and assign json to that dictionary.

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String] {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let success  = Int(json["success"]!)
                            let loginvaluefromdb = json["login"]
                            if(success == 1){
                                let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViwController") as! yourViwController
                    viewController.dictJson = json
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . let me try it first . thanks :D

Comment: "dictJson" is from where ?

Comment: in your viewcontroller where you have taken IBOutlet for loginlbl  place this dictJson property. let dictJson = Dictionary<String,String>()

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(success == 1){
           self.outputLbl.text = loginvaluefromdb;
           // Here you trigger the segue
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToViewController", sender: loginvaluefromdb)
           return
         }
```

You need to pass the data in prepare for segue method :
Here is the editec code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToViewController" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            // Here you will copy tha data you want to pass
            destination.passedData = sender as? String
            print("Sender Value: \(sender)")
        }
    }
}
```