# How to send UITableViewCell data to another ViewController in swift?

Tags: swift, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to send a single message from the `messageArray` to another `UIViewController` so that I can load up the message's comments. How can I send the message data structure over when the cell is clicked on?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as? feedMessagesCell else {return UITableViewCell()}


        let message = messageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(content: message.content, userName: message.userName)
return cell

    }
```

Comment: You can refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26374173/8330469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't `guard` reusing cells. The code must not crash. If it does it reveals a design mistake. And use the API which returns a non-optional cell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell", for: indexPath) as! feedMessagesCell
```

To send data to another view controller create a segue in Interface Builder by connecting the **table view cell** to the destination controller.

In `prepare(for segue` the sender is the cell. Change `PushFeedDetail` to the real identifier and `MyDestinationController` to the real class. Create a `message` property in the destination controller. Get the index path from the cell and pass the item in the data source array.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PushFeedDetail" { 
        let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! feedMessagesCell)!
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! MyDestinationController
        let message = messageArray[selectedIndexPath.row]
        destinationController.message = message
    }
}
```