# Using Delegate how to pass data between classes ios

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have parsed data from JSON link in a data source file how can I use that data to display information in the main view controller.

Comment: Please add more information. where you are getting data? does you want to show in previous controller of navigation stack or on the same controller?

Comment: Using delegate method how can I access the data from the data source file.
Access data of one class into another class.
From JSON link I am parsing data and want to display the data in the from another class

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift

Comment: I have added an answer how delegate works. Hope this helps

Comment: When asking a question, you should show us some code of what you've tried and enter far more details of exactly what you're trying to do. That means that the community can give you a more precise answer rather than having to make some assumptions on the detail and possibly give answers that are not relevant to you. Here is a link to some help on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

//Create protocol in second class from where you want to send data to previous one

```
protocol SampleDelegate: class {
  func getData(data: YourDataType)
}
```

//Your sample class/ViewController

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
// MARK:- Delegate
weak var delegate: SampleDelegate?
```

//From where you want to send data

```
 delegate?.getData(data: Data)
}
```

//Main Class/ViewController

```
let detailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SampleViewController") as! SampleViewController
detailViewController.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)

func getData(data: YourDataType){
     //This function get called when you call this method from Smapleview controller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that,you want to pass data from VCB To VCA

IMPLEMENT DELEGATION

> Create a protocol at the very top of VCB.

```
protocol VCBDelegate {
    func passingName(string: String)
}
```

> Now inside of our VCB class, we need to declare a delegate variable.

```
var delegate: VCBDelegate?
```

> Then inside of btnPassDataPressed function, add the following code:

```
delegate?. passingName(string: "Sent from VCFinal")
```

> adopt our VCBDelegate protocol. In VCA and make delegate self in
>   viewDidLoad

```
class VCA: UIViewController, VCFinalDelegate
```

> Go ahead and add the passingName function inside of VCA.

```
func passingName(string: String) {
   print("Notified")
}
```