# Pass data to view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a screen with 2 buttons, `A` and `B`. When you press the buttons they go to the same view, with a button `C`. When pressed `C` depending 
if you pressed `A` or `B` they go to different views.

I have something like this, but I have two problems. First, it't not working, even when I hardcode `Button A` to `mealTableViewController.from`. Second, I don't know how to pass witch button was pressed to `mealTableViewController.from`.

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let mealTableViewController = segue.destination as? MealTableViewController else {
            return
        }
        mealTableViewController.from = "Button A"
    }
}
```

In the storyboard attached to `HomeViewController` there are two button with a `Show segue to Meal Table View Controller`

Then, I have `MealTableViewController`, with a button connected to the action `boton`, that depending the value of `from`, it transition to one screen or to other.

```
class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var from: String?

    @IBAction func boton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if from == "Button A" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowMealView", sender: self)
        } else {
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowOther", sender: self)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Segues have identifiers.  In the *Attributes Inspector* assign `"buttonA"` to the segue from button A, and `"buttonB"` from buttonB.  Check the identifier in `prepare(for:sender:)` with `if segue.identifier == "buttonA" { mealTableViewController.from = "Button A" } else if segue.identifier == "buttonB" { mealTableViewController.from = "Button B" }`

Comment: Can you explain how you connected the HomeViewController to the MealTableViewController in the storyboard? As in, did you ctrl+drag from the button A/B to the MealTableViewController?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift) and a large number of other questions

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this example and it works as expected.

Button A action perform segue with identifier `Button A`

Button B action perform segue with identifier `Button B`

MealTableViewController has segues attached with identifiers `ShowMealView` and `ShowOther`(not Button C)

Storyboard:

[image]

FirstViewController

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        guard let mealTableViewController = segue.destination as? MealTableViewController else {
            return
        }

        mealTableViewController.from = segue.identifier

    }

}
```

MealTableViewController

```
class MealTableViewController: UIViewController {

    var from: String?

    @IBAction func boton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if from == "Button A" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowMealView", sender: self)
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowOther", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Check your segue identifiers and where they are attached to:

[image]

[image]