# use performSegueWithIdentifier to get functionality of DestinationViewController, but not show it up

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a WatchKit App that updates some labels with data from `NSUserDefaults`. These `defaults` are updated by two different `ViewControllers` in the iOS App.
If I press a button in `ViewController1`, the view in the iOS App as well as the one in the WatchKit App gets updated (using NSTimer to update every second). So far so good, but now I need a `defaults` value to be shown on the Watch that is updated by iOS Apps `ViewController2` only. I would like to stay on the view of `ViewController1` but when I press the button, it should kind of 'run all the stuff' that is in `ViewController2` (especially updating the specific `NSUserDefault` value after all the controllers math has been done) but without moving to it.

I have tried `ViewController2().viewDidLoad()` in the `@IBAction` function of the button in `ViewController1`, but this leads to a crash. Have also tried to use a Delegate like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204255/access-the-instance-of-a-viewcontroller-from-another-in-swift) and then to get my value from a hidden label, but could not make it work.

When I simply move to `ViewController2` with `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToView2", sender: self)`
 all works well (all lables on the Watch are updated), but I do not want to move to View2, I want to stay on View1 when the button is pressed but get the `NSUserDefaults` updated from View2 first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fighting against bad design decisions.

You need to rethink your design. If you have functionality that is tied to a view controller that you need elsewhere, you need to pull that functionality out into a non view controller class and call that.

I often create a Utils class that I use. If the methods don't need state data, I'll make them class methods. If they need persistent state data, I make the utils class a singleton.

I then call the methods I need inside the singleton.