# Perform segue to another Navigation Controller without showing Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

I have a root `Tab Host Controller` with two `Navigation Controller` tab siblings: (1) Nearby Stops and (2) Saved Stops. Each of these has a `View Controller` respectively.

I would like to perform a segue from one of the sibling `View Controllers` to another `Navigation Controller` with Stop Schedule View Controller embedded in it, with the following requirements:

1. The root `Tab Bar` should not show at the bottom of this `View Controller`
2. I need to pass a `Stop` object to this View Controller before performing the segue

Storyboard:
[image]

Currently, I am performing a segue this way, though the `Tab Bar` remains on the Stop Schedule View Controller when it shouldn't.

```
func showStopSchedule(stop: Stop) {
    let stopScheduleController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StopScheduleViewController") as! StopScheduleViewController

    stopScheduleController.stop = stop    // pass data object

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(stopScheduleController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the additional navigation controller in front of your stop schedule controller?

Comment: I included it so that the Tab Bar would not be included in the View Controller.

Comment: Ok, so remove it, and then use the code from my answer to hide the tab bar when required.  This will also make user navigation simpler as they can simply go back to where they started from.  SwiftArchitect is correct too; you aren't using the segue in the storyboard.  You can use `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `prepareForSegue` to pass the stop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply set the `hidden` property of your tab bar when the stop schedule view controller is displayed and unhide the tab bar before that view controller disappears

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden=true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden=false
}
```

Update:  To animate the transition you can use this:

```
class StopViewController: UIViewController {

    var barFrame:CGRect?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden=true
        if  let tabBar=self.tabBarController?.tabBar {
           self.barFrame=tabBar.frame

           UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
               let newBarFrame=CGRectMake(self.barFrame!.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, self.barFrame!.size.width, self.barFrame!.size.height)
               tabBar.frame=newBarFrame
            }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                tabBar.hidden=true
            })

        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden=false;
        if self.barFrame != nil {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                let newBarFrame=CGRectMake(self.barFrame!.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-self.barFrame!.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.barFrame!.size.height)
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame=newBarFrame
            })

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does hide the tab bar, though there is a noticeable fade animation on the tab bar when the view controller appears.

Comment: It's a trade off. Personally I prefer it to the modal transition you get with a second navigation controller and you don't lose the navigation stack.  See my updated answer for an animated alternative

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, I will try your solution and SwiftArchitect's to see which works best.

Comment: @Paulw11: beautiful!

Comment: I updated my code to prevent the tab bar from appearing briefly when the device is rotated and to behave correctly if the device is rotated before returning to the first view

Comment: The tab bar sliding out is a very nice effect. I wonder if it could be managed by a constraint. How do you push that navigation controller, and does the *< Back* button come with it (it didn't in my answer)

Comment: I don't think so, because the tab bar is created by the tab bar controller and I don't think it uses constraints

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm leaning towards you're answer since the animation of the tab bar hiding/revealing is nice. However, I'm noticing a small issue where the area behind the tab bar is giving incorrect colours. See here: http://gfycat.com/VibrantGleamingCollardlizard

Comment: It looks like the background color of the view doesn't match the background color of the table, so initially you see the view color and then the table expands down.

Comment: It appears that it is masking (?) the background since when transitioning from Saved Stops you can see partial white bg and partial black bg of the Stop Schedule.

Comment: That is the other possibility - When the tab bar moves down it may reveal a previously hidden view background that isn't a consistent colour?

Comment: Yea when two View Controllers have different bg colours you will see that happen. Unfortunately, I require them to be different colours. :/

Comment: At this stage, I would investigate a custom transition to control timing, and not solely rely on `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @SwiftArchitect To work around this, I disabled the animation in viewWillAppear() and just hide the tab bar immediately. Though, the animation to show the tab bar again works fine and can remain.

Comment: It isn't happening for me with different view background colors. I changed my first VC to include a tableview.  I have only been testing on the simulator..I am just going to try on my phone

Comment: It looks to me that it may be something to do with the delay in loading the stop data; the tableview redraws at that point.  You could try a simple `UIActivityView` in the center of the screen and show that & hide the tableview until the data is loaded, then once you have data for the table show the table and hide the activity view

Comment: It is OK on my phone too. I will try adding a tableview with delayed load to my "stop" screen

Comment: Even doing that, it still works OK for me - http://gfycat.com/FlimsyCommonFirecrest - Perhaps double check how you are laying everything out/constraints

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 I'll investigate further. Not sure what's causing it, but in your gif I noticed the last cell appears after some predetermined delay too. Though you aren't seeing the tear between bg colours. Odd.

Comment: Yeah, I just faked a network load  - in `viewDidLoad` I dispatched a background block to sleep for 3 seconds, then load static data into an array and call `reloadData`

Comment: This is what I meant by hiding the tableview until it has loaded - http://gfycat.com/ObviousVariableCapybara

Comment: I tried hiding the entire tableview but it is still happening :/

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the segue you just defined in your Storyboard. Instead, you are currently reloading your `StopScheduleViewController` manually, whereas you should only perform the `segue` you already have defined.

Add an *Identifier* to each of the **Storyboard Segue** you want to invoke programmatically,

[image: segue identifier]

then load them in this manner:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showStopSchedule", sender: self)
}
```

[image: Use Storyboard segue animation]

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't answer the question as to how to hide the tab bar.  This should probably be a comment.

Comment: It does. Loading the segue hides the tab bar.

Comment: Hmm, yes.  I didn't notice the additional navigation controller that they have inserted in front of the final view controller.  This is probably unnecessary

Comment: With this approach how can I also pass the `Stop` object to the View Controller?

Comment: Use `- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017026/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-segue

Comment: Is the extra `Navigation Controller` unnecessary? Should I keep it or leave it?

Comment: That is actually up to you. You can try both ways and see what fits best. In my demo, I have kept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only hide the navigationController the below code works.

```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```