# Can I pass the plist data via segue in Xcode?objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, segue

I am doing something that require to display the `plist` data on the `Label` on the second controller. When I click the `TableView` on the first controller, but it seems like I can't pass it by segue. Is there any way to pass the data to the next ViewController?
I just did this for the `plist`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _theTableView.dataSource=self;
    _theTableView.delegate=self;
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theplist.plist" ofType:@""];
    array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

and the tableview

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [array1 count];
}
```

and the segue

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReusedCell"];}

    NSDictionary*item = array1[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"movien"];
    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender     
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
   {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       NSString *object = tableObjects[indexPath.row];
       DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

      [controller setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017026/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-segue

Comment: there are many questions in SO on passing data using segues.Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I assume that `tableObjects` should hold the data from the plist. Some thoughts:

* Did you verify that `object` isn't nil?
* Is `controller` instantiated?
* Does `setDetailItem` use the parameter `object`?