# How to Pass values in between segues

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

So I have 2 View Controllers that I want to pass values in between and have the following code

```
@IBAction func analysisButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if expensesRecieved.count > 0{
        let categoryAnalysisController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryVC") as! CategoryAnalysis
        //            var categoryAnalysisController: CategoryAnalysis = CategoryAnalysis(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        categoryAnalysisController.collection = collectionDisplayed.text
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "categoryAnalysis", sender:(Any).self)
    }
```

What I want to do, is that if expensesRecieved's count is greater than 0, execute the segue and pass the value, and if it's not then give an alert and don't do anything.

In the past I have used a prepareSegue method but never done it like this. I have tried a couple of methods, one being like this and none of them have worked. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between View Controllers using Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017026/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-segue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func analysisButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if expensesRecieved.count > 0 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "categoryAnalysis", sender: nil)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "categoryAnalysis" {
        guard let viewController = segue.destination as? YourViewController else { return }
        viewController.expensesReceived = self.expencesReceived
    } else {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a global variable in destination view controller named "data_from_last_viewcontroller" you can override this method and do something like this,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

 if segue.identifier == "categoryAnalysis" 
 {
    if let dist = segue.destination as? YOURNEXTVIEWCONTROLLER
    {
         dest.data_from_last_viewcontroller = YOUR_DATA_TO_PASS_HERE  
    }
 }
}
```

**what is happening here**

this method is called everytime a segue is about to perform, in your cases right after the performSegue line.
it takes the destination Viewcontroller and sets the value of the destination ViewController like this so it ready when the new viewcontroller starts its gears.